# Python : Which packages I need to install in order to import mysql.connector

Tags: mysql-python, importerror, python-import

I tried to find the answer all over the web but I didn't get any idea.
I downloaded Python 3.4 for Windows and I want to import mysql.connector.
What should I do ?

Please If someone can guide me what I exactly need to do in order to import mysql.connector properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you want the original MySQL connector and not any other libraries out there?
Then this is the way to go:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source-windows.html